# How can we use required field validator on User Control in aspx page

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-controls

How can we use required field validator on User Control in aspx page?

I have one user control that have one **drop down**. I am using this control on my page. I want to use **required field validator** on this drop down.

How can I use?

Comment: You want this at postback or on client?

Comment: asp is not asp.net. retag please